# How can I see my stack exchange account login history

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

I would like to be able to see my stack exchange account activity. i.e. history of logins with IP address. I remember browsing to that page yesterday so I know it exists but I cannot seem to find it today.

Comment: Clicking on `my logins` on your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1531913/whyvez) shows last-used dates on your various logins, is that what you remember?

Comment: no... it was actually a list of logins per account but it was a list of the last x number of logins. There was a list of them with the date and login IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [StackID](http://openid.stackexchange.com), then [StackId's user page](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) has the detailed listing of your logn history

[image]